# Python: Using subprocess and Popen to Print output

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, popen, shlex

I have a python program that will cat a file and then print out the output only if the word "oranges" is found in the output. I was wondering how I could reverse this and have the program NOT output anything if "oranges" is found in the output?

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import commands, os, string
import sys
import fileinput
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import shlex

        cmd = "cat /root/newfile.txt"

        args = shlex.split(cmd)

        p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = p.communicate()
        if out.find("oranges") > -1:
                print out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
if not "oranges" in out:
    print out
```